# Where to download Ubuntu core for armhf?

Tags: ubuntu-core, arm

I like to put Ubuntu on the NXP board with an ARM hardware float iMX6 processor. But I can't find a place to download Ubuntu core any more as I need to get the compatible rootfs from it. The links are dead

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-core-14.04.4-core-armhf.tar.gz

referred from https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-330147

and current links no longer support generic armhf except for a few models:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/18/

I wonder if you have any idea about what's the cause and where to find compatible core & rootfs now?

Thanks for comments